# how can you filter/block outgoing email addresses with rails 2.x actionmailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, block, actionmailer

for non-production rails 2.x environments i want to block/filter any outgoing emails that aren't addressed to people in my organization (e.g. "*@where-i-work.com").

please note, i don't want to block email entirely - i know i can just write them to the logs in test mode - i need emails to internal employees to be delivered.

thanks.

Comment: There's a gem for this!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393213/rails-redirect-all-outgoing-emails-to-single-address-for-testing
https://github.com/pboling/sanitize_email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try extending the `Mail::Message.deliver` function in your environment.rb file - something like (not tested - just demo code!):

```
class Mail::Message
    def deliver_with_recipient_filter
        self.to = self.to.to_a.delete_if {|to| !(to =~ /.*@where-i-work.com\Z/)} if RAILS_ENV != production
        self.deliver_without_recipient_filter unless self.to.blank?
    end

    alias_method_chain :deliver, :recipient_filter
end
```

Note that this id for Rails 3 - I think all versions of Rails 2 use TMail instead of Mail, so you'll need to override something else if you're not using Rails 3.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

based on @Xavier's rails 3 proposal i was able to get it working in rails 2:

```
class ActionMailer::Base
  def deliver_with_recipient_filter!(mail = @mail) 
    unless 'production' == Rails.env
      mail.to = mail.to.to_a.delete_if do |to| 
        !to.ends_with?('where-i-work.com')
      end
    end
    unless mail.to.blank?
      deliver_without_recipient_filter!(mail)
    end
  end
  alias_method_chain 'deliver!'.to_sym, :recipient_filter
end
```

Comment: If you're using aws-ses you'll need to override `AWS::SES::Base` instead of `ActionMailer::Base`.